# Как изменить цвет месяцев google jsapi

Tags: javascript, frontend, google-chart

Ребята помогите пожалуйста с графиком
Мне вот надо изменить цвет поля что выделил на картинке, в js не силен , так что не бейте

```
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {
    packages: ["timeline"]
  });
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  
  function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      id: 'Position'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      id: 'Name'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      role: 'tooltip',
      p: {'html': true}
    })
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'date',
      id: 'Start'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'date',
      id: 'End'
    });
  
    dataTable.addRows([
      [
        'Features', 
        'Release 3.0 01.10.2014', 
        'Das erste Projekt mit silver.e-shop 3.0. geht online', 
        new Date(2014, 10, 1), 
        new Date(2014, 10, 7)
      ],
      [
        'Features', 
        'Release 3.1 01.04.2014', 
        '<ul> \
          <li>Payment (Ogone, Telecash)</li> \
          <li>Cockpit</li> \
        </ul>', 
        new Date(2015, 4, 1), 
        new Date(2015, 4, 7)
      ],
      [
        'Features', 
        'Release 3.2 01.10.2015', 
        '<ul> \
          <li>Bestellhistorie</li> \
          <li>Delegate-Funktion</li> \
          <li>Produktvarianten un Set-Artikel</li> \
          <li>Customer Center</li> \
          <li>Produktverfleiche</li> \
        </ul>',
        new Date(2015, 10, 1), 
        new Date(2015, 10, 7)
      ],
      [
        'Features', 
        'Release 3.3 01.04.2016', 
        '<ul> \
          <li>Cluster/Load-Balancing</li> \
        </ul>', 
        new Date(2016, 4, 1), 
        new Date(2016, 4, 7)
      ],
      [
        'Technical', 
        'ez 5.4.2', 
        'Info goes here', 
        new Date(2015, 4, 1), 
        new Date(2015, 10, 1)
      ],
      [
        'Technical', 
        'eZ 6.0', 
        'Info goes here', 
        new Date(2015, 10, 1), 
        new Date(2016, 4, 1)
      ],
      [
        'Strategy', 
        'Clustering', 
        'Clustering support', 
        new Date(2015, 8, 1), 
        new Date(2016, 2, 1)
      ],
    ]);
    // blue - #0D539D
    // orange - #F4772C
    // green - #289B00 
    var
      options = {
        timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true, rowLabelStyle: { fontName: 'Arial Black'} },
        colors: ['#0D539D', '#F4772C', '#289B00'],
        tooltip: {
          isHtml: true
        },
        legend: 'none',
        forceIFrame: true,
        width: 1000,
        height: 180
      };
  
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Все было куда проще)
Нужно было удалить forcelIframe
Чтобы все на заворачивалось в iframe
Ну и тогда норм крепятся стили